# Minimum age for SO Meetups

Tags: discussion, age

I've been asked by a user who wishes to remain anonymous what the minimum age for attending today's meetups is.

Comment: Related question: what's the maximum age?

Comment: Sure.. A "user". It's you isn't it?

Comment: No; it isn't.  I couldn't go due to a time conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not ask this directly in the meetup posting for the specific location? It probably depends on the venue.

Comment: I wish more people were coming to the Indy one...

Comment: ... and on the legislation.

Comment: That's the one closest to me, but today happens to be a terrible day. Ah well